# Closing ANSI color style

Tags: shell, colors, printf

`255` is *white*, so `printf '\u001b[38;5;255mfoo\u001b[m\n'` outputs `foo` with white foreground.

- `\u001b[38;5;255m` sets the white foreground
- `\u001b[m` resets the ANSI style

Instead of resetting the style, I want to properly close the white color.

How can I do that?

An example how to close the black color is:

```
printf '\u001b[30mfoo\u001b[39m\n'
```

How to close a color what is opened with `\u001b[38;5;<color>`?

Comment: What do you mean by "close a color"?

Comment: Maybe you could use a color key, a color lock, a color door or the `close()` syscall in order to close the color… ohwait…

Comment: @RowlandShaw `\u001b[30m` opens the black foreground and `\u001b[39m` closes it. I imagine it's more or less like HTML elements work. Isn't that clear...?

Comment: I imagine it more as a command to say "make everything from now on white" and "make everything from now on whatever your default is"

Comment: @RowlandShaw Not really. The *default* is `\001b[0m`. But the styles can be combined too: `printf '\u001b[30m\u001b[3mf\u001b[23moo\u001b[39m\n'` outputs `foo` in black, but with `f` in italic style.

Comment: What is the difference between "closing" and resetting? Closing just means going back to default, what else do you need? Why is `\u001b[38;5;255mfoo\u001b[39m` not enough?

Comment: @terdon `\u001b[0m` resets everything (foreground, background, style). I only want to reset the foreground. Your last question is a good point: what does the `\u001b[39m` snippet? Does it reset only the foreground? I guessed it's related to black.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Ah,  I see.  As for the last one,  I don't really know.  You said that `\u001b[39` closes the black,  so I guessed that it could also close the white.  I am not at my computer so I can't check the anti table but it should be easy enough to find.

Comment: @terdon I wonder if there is a place where all these things are documented...

Comment: @IonicăBizău `39` sets default color *only* for foreground, whereas `49` does the same for background. I'm not sure how reliable those two codes are across different terminals, probably not much. You can find good article about ANSI codes on wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: @jimmij You're correct. I fixed this in the latest version of [`couleurs`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/couleurs). You can post an answer if you like.